# Syntactic or Lexical Error in writing an interpret

Tags: parsing, syntax-error, lexical-analysis, parse-error

For a school project I have to write an interpret in C for programming languge similar to Swift. I'm encountering an issue in my code, and I'm not sure if it's a syntactic or lexical error. In the following line of code:
`result = a -/ b` 
And how should I recognize what is lexical and what syntax Error. Because I dont know if -/ is an invalid token and it is lexical error or after minus there should be divide so it is syntax error.

Same for example in code: if (result ==> ) it is a syntax error because after == there shouldnt be symbol > or it is lexical because ==> is not valid token

Comment: We can't tell, it depends on the language you're implementing. Do you have a formal grammar?

Comment: @Bergi it is a subset from s Swift

Comment: Well *which* subset? Do you have to parse the entire Swift language but not interpret all of it?

Comment: Did you have a look at https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/lexicalstructure#Operators?

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with Swift, but generally, if the language has a `-/` token defined, then the lexer would break the input that you have into the tokens `result` `=` `a` `-/` `b`. If it doesn't, then the break-up will be `result` `=` `a` `-` `/` `b`, so there should be no lexical error in either case. Unless the `-/` operator is defined by the language, this will indeed trigger a syntax error later on in the compilation process.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError thank you so much